RLS in Azure Data Explorer - Allowed operators issue
I'm attempting to implement RLS in ADX on already ingested data. The RLS policy function I'm creating looks like this.
.create-or-alter function with (docstring = 'Restricts access to data.', folder = 'RLS') RestrictAccess(TableName: string) {
    table(TableName)
    | join kind=leftsemi (
            AccessTable
            | extend 
                current_member=case(
                    current_principal_is_member_of('aadgroup=00000000-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEEEEEEEEE'), 'foo',
                    current_principal_is_member_of('aadgroup=11111111-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEEEEEEEEE'), 'bar',
                    current_principal_is_member_of('aadgroup=22222222-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEEEEEEEEE'), 'baz',
                    'unknown'
                )
            | where current_member == groupName
            | distinct deviceId
        ) on deviceId
}

my access table looks like this
.set-or-append async AccessTable with(folder = 'RLS') <|
datatable(deviceId: string, groupName: string)[
    'A0000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444', 'foo',
    'B0000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444', 'foo',
    'B0000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444', 'bar',
    'D0000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444', 'baz'
];

Then I run the policy like this
.alter table MyTable policy row_level_security enable "RestrictAccess('MyTable')"

However, I get the error
Error

Error during execution of a policy operation: Error in row_level_security query for database("MyDatabase").table("MyTable"): the following operators were blocked: 'summarize' (only the following operators are allowed: 'as', 'distinct', 'extend', 'join', 'limit', 'project', 'project-away', 'project-keep', 'project-rename', 'project-reorder', 'union', 'where')

As you can see, I'm only using allowed operators! What could be the issue?

The distinct operator is essentially an alias to summarize by

I get the same error message. Even if we limit the RLS function to:
table(TableName)
| distinct deviceId, groupName
Still, it does not work. If we replace distinct by summarize take_any(1) it does not work as well. So I think this is a bug. Maybe the error message is just misleading (?). I recommend opening a ticket via Azure portal.
